# How do I find an object key written in any format?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to find a string in any way it is written in an object received.

```
example

"OUTPUT", "OUT PUT", "out put", "ouT Put"
```

`test.hasOwnProperty("OUTPUT")` works for only this case. I do not want to repeat the same for each case. Is there a better way to get this done?

Comment: you could remove all the spaces, and compare lowercase values against each other.

Comment: `Object.entries(example).find(([key, value]) => key.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "") == "output")`?

Comment: Depends: are you assuming there will never be any collisions between spaced and non-spaced keys? Upper/lower? I mean, if not, just write a tiny method to iterate over whatever combos you think you want. This seems awful, though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var object = {"OUTPUT":"value"};

var prop1 = "OUTPUT",
prop2 = "OUT PUT",
prop3 = "out put",
prop4="ouT Put";

console.log(object.hasOwnProperty(encodeURI(prop2).replace(/%20/g,'').toUpperCase()));

console.log(object.hasOwnProperty(encodeURI(prop2).replace(/%20/g,'').toUpperCase()));

console.log(object.hasOwnProperty(encodeURI(prop2).replace(/%20/g,'').toUpperCase()));

console.log(object.hasOwnProperty(encodeURI(prop2).replace(/%20/g,'').toUpperCase()));
```